# How would I change my code from a while loop to a do while loop in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

```
public class Number {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int start = 45; 
    int stop = 175;
    int count = 0; 
    while (start++ < stop) { 
        if (start % 2 == 0) { 
            count++;// adds one to count
            System.out.println("Found even number " + start);

        }

        if (count == 15) break;
    }

}
```

This is my current code right now I and I am not sure how to convert this While loop into a Do While loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing condition has a side effect. You have to ensure this happens before each loop iteration.

```
start++;
do {
  // Existing body.
} while (start++ < stop);
```

Also, note that this only works because the guard condition is initially true, so the loop always iterates at least once. If you couldn't guarantee that, you need to use something like the following to make them equivalent, since a do/while loop always executes at least once:

```
if (start++ < stop) {
  do {
    // Existing body.
  } while (start++ < stop);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just would have to do:

```
do
{
// code
} while (++start < stop);
```

Hope it helps.